# Kubernetes deployment required to provide application configuration path

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, kubectl

I'm trying to deploy my application which needs the configuration form /root/properties folder.

**With Docker**

1. docker build -t config .
2. docker run -p8080:8080 -v /root/properties:/root/properties --name config -d config

**Running OK.**

Now.. **With Kubernetes cluster , i'm not able to attach -v as done in docker run.**

kubectl create deployment deploy-config --image=localhost:5000/config --port=8080 -v /root/properties

with -v pod not created. How to provide the properties folder path..??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a [config map](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/)

Or possibly a [pvc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/).

It depends on the details which have not really been shared.